# Dynamics CRM FetchXML - Birthday is today

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible using FetchXML to find out the Contacts who's birthday is for today?  For example 4/1/2000, 4/1/2001, 4/1/2002?

I don't want to write custom code to do this if possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not possible without additional coding... General approach is to add 2 fields - day of birth and month of birth, populate it during creation/update of a record and use mentioned fields after.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<condition attribute="birthdate" operator="today"/>
```

EDIT:
One way to accomplish this would be to create a recurring workflow job that runs a custom activity daily that sets an attribute to true for all the people whose birthday is today.

Another option might be to create a retrieve multiple plugin that changes the query criteria dynamically, but you might need to also include additional attribute(s) to just keep track of the month and day separately from the year.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, great point. I read through the question, but didn't think it through all the way :) I agree with Adrii. I don't see how this would be possible without coding.